# Setting a color on a container that container a ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

Ok I don't want to take advantage and post too many question but I have another flutter related question. I'm trying to set a background color to a card that I created that holds a ListView, but as soon as I give the container any property I repeatedly get this error:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderColoredBox#0caae relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

code below:

```
class ThisView extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'this-view';

  @override
  _ThisViewState createState() => _ThisViewState();
}

class _ThisViewState extends State<ThisView> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Title',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Title"),
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.Green),
          body: Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  customCard1(),
                  Container(
                    // color: Colors.white,
                      child: Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 24, right: 24, top: 28, bottom: 14),
                            child: Text(
                              "Subtitle",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24, bottom: 8),
                            child: Text(
                              "23rd of Oct",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: ListView(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height: 200,
                                  color: Colors.amber[600],
                                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: 200,
                                  color: Colors.amber[500],
                                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: 200,
                                  color: Colors.amber[100],
                                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ]),
                  ))
                ],
              ))),
    );
  }
}
```

I commented out where I would like to set the color for the card.
In the future I am going to dynamic render the listView so it might not take up the whole space so I want the card background color set instead of something like setting the whole background color to white and just putting a grey SizeBox in-between the cards

Does anyone know what might be causing this error when I try to add properties to the Container?

note: I took this code out of a custom card Widget I had so I could maybe debug it easier, also I didn't include customCard1 in this code snippet.

Please let me know if anymore info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Container need the know what about the size. First check your device size with MediaQuery class later give the container size what do you want.

Sample like that

```
class ThisView extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'this-view';

  @override
  _ThisViewState createState() => _ThisViewState();
}

class _ThisViewState extends State<ThisView> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(contex).size.height,
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(contex).size.width,
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Title',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Title"),
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.Green),
          body: Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  customCard1(),
                  Container(
                     height :screenHeight/4,
                     width :screenWidth/2,    
                    // color: Colors.white,
                      child: Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 24, right: 24, top: 28, bottom: 14),
                            child: Text(
                              "Subtitle",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24, bottom: 8),
                            child: Text(
                              "23rd of Oct",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: ListView(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height: 200,
                                  color: Colors.amber[600],
                                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: 200,
                                  color: Colors.amber[500],
                                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: 200,
                                  color: Colors.amber[100],
                                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ]),
                  ))
                ],
              ))),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Setting hard dimensions for the container worked :D however because the card above it changed height based on what state it is in so I have to update my calculation (size of the screen - status bar - nav bar - customcard1) every time the top card changed states. And that does work but if any of those widgets change in the future this is going to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Please check, is it work for you?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ThisView extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'this-view';

  @override
  _ThisViewState createState() => _ThisViewState();
}

class _ThisViewState extends State<ThisView> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Title',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Title"),
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.green),
          body: Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  customCard1(),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 24, right: 24, top: 28, bottom: 14),
                            child: Text(
                              "Subtitle",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding:
                            EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24, bottom: 8),
                            child: Text(
                              "23rd of Oct",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: ListView(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height: 200,
                                  color: Colors.amber[600],
                                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: 200,
                                  color: Colors.amber[500],
                                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: 200,
                                  color: Colors.amber[100],
                                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ]),
                  )
                ],
              ))),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(178, 186, 187, 1.0),
```

In fromRGBO R --> Red, G -- Green, B --> Blue, O --> opacity is alpha channel of this color as a double, with 0.0 being transparent and 1.0 being fully opaque.

https://htmlcolorcodes.com/ refer this link for color combinations.

This will set the background color. You can also use

```
home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
```

or any other color.. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors-class.html

Complete code:

```
class ThisView extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'this-view';

  @override
  _ThisViewState createState() => _ThisViewState();
}

class _ThisViewState extends State<ThisView> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Title',
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(178, 186, 187, 1.0),
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Title"),
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.Green),
          body: Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  customCard1(),
                  Container(
                    // color: Colors.white,
                      child: Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 24, right: 24, top: 28, bottom: 14),
                            child: Text(
                              "Subtitle",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24, bottom: 8),
                            child: Text(
                              "23rd of Oct",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: ListView(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height: 200,
                                  color: Colors.amber[600],
                                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: 200,
                                  color: Colors.amber[500],
                                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: 200,
                                  color: Colors.amber[100],
                                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ]),
                  ))
                ],
              ))),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a container to color the background, you can use the Card widget color property which changes the background color of the card. so something like Card(color: Colors.white).